# Openldap backsql add user to group with groupofNames

Tags: mysql, ldap, openldap

I am using Openldap with mysql as backsql.In my db structure there are three tables
Users,Group,User_to_Usergroup.
My ldif file looks like

```
 dn: cn=Marketing,ou=Department,dc=org,dc=o
    changetype: modify
    ou: Marketing
    add: member
    member: cn=Your Name,ou=Department,dc=org,dc=o
```

I have these two entries

- cn=Marketing,ou=Department,dc=org,dc=o
- cn=Your Name,ou=Department,dc=org,dc=o

  in ldap_entries and i want to add Group DN and the user Dn to  User_to_Usergroup table using **groupofNames** attribute 'member'.

Somehow it is fetching only the Group DN id and not the user Dn is which is returning as 0 and with the error **unable to prettify value #1 of Attribute Description member**.
Also have two entries for groupofName cn and member with the corresponding sql's.

Errorlog:

```
backsql_modify_internal(): adding new values for attribute "member"
5370bc16    backsql_modify_internal(): arg(2)=**3**
5370bc16    backsql_modify_internal(): arg(1)="cn=Your Name ,ou=Department,dc=org,dc=o"; executing "insert into users_to_usergroup (id,ivt_user_id,ivt_usergroup_id) values (newusergroup(),?,?)"
5370bc16    backsql_modify_internal(): add_proc execution failed (rc=-1, prc=0)
5370bc16 Return code: -1
5370bc16    nativeErrCode=1062 SQLengineState=23000 msg="[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.35-2-log]Duplicate entry '0-3' for key 'Index_2'"
backsql_modify_internal(): adding new values for attribute "member"
retrieving all attributes
5370bc16 ==>backsql_get_attr_vals(): oc="groupOfNames" attr="cn" keyval=3
5370bc16 backsql_get_attr_vals(): number of values in query: 1
5370bc16 <==backsql_get_attr_vals()
5370bc16 ==>backsql_get_attr_vals(): oc="groupOfNames" attr="member" keyval=3
5370bc16 backsql_get_attr_vals(): number of values in query: 2
5370bc16 >>> dnPretty: < >
5370bc16 ==>backsql_get_attr_vals("cn=Marketing,ou=Department,dc=org,dc=o"): unable to prettify value #0 of AttributeDescription member (21)
5370bc16 >>> dnPretty: <Your Name>
5370bc16 ==>backsql_get_attr_vals("cn=Marketing,ou=Department,dc=org,dc=o"): unable to prettify value #1 of AttributeDescription member (21)
5370bc16 <==backsql_get_attr_vals()
5370bc16 ==>backsql_get_attr_vals(): oc="groupOfNames" attr="objectClass" keyval=3
5370bc16 backsql_get_attr_vals(): number of values in query: 0
```

Am i missing something? For any more info please let me know .. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a closer look:

```
Duplicate entry '0-3' for key 'Index_2'
```

Looks like the user is already a member.

Comment: the issue was because the add_proc sql with the entry for member attribute should have written with a complete select query from ldap_extries instead of ? symbol,and just because of that it was returning 0 all the time.anyway resolved the issue! thanks for the support